# size of the NSString to fit on UItextview

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, uitextview

i want to find the size of NSString to display on UITextview. It is working good for English. But if the string is other languages like spanish, hindi, japanese means it is working slow:

CGSize ContentSize=[MainContentString 
        sizeWithFont:TextView.font
        constrainedToSize:CSize
        lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

Is there a way to do it faster?

Comment: Please show the code that is "working slow".

Comment: ContentSize=[[MainContentString substringFromIndex:index] sizeWithFont:TextView.font constrainedToSize:CSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a very easy way to do resizing of the UITextView to its correct height of the content. It can be done using the UITextView contentSize.

```
CGRect frame = _textView.frame;
frame.size.height = _textView.contentSize.height;
_textView.frame = frame;
```

Comment: i dont want to resize the textview. i want to find out the CGsize of the NSString. it is also working fine. but it is working slow for other languages like hindi, tamil.

Answer (score 0):

Check out UIView's [autoresizesSubviews](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW6) and [contentMode](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW99) - play with them in the storyboard.

Try it both with and without your implementation - see if it works.